# Is running a for loop in a Volley response listener okay?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm getting this in my logcat: `skipped X frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` where X is usually between 40 and 60.

I'm new to android development and I'm not sure how much Volley does with AsyncTasks. In my fragment, I send a request to the server for JSON like such:

```
{ "networks" : [ { "name" : "a name", "external_id" : "an external_id" }, ... ] }
```

The `...` is just a place holder for elements that are of the same form as the first one I showed in the array.

I do basically all of the work in the `onActivityCreated` function in my Fragment.

Here is the code and I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. Also, the point of the for loop is to loop through the JSONArray and turn each element into its own model which I then pass to an ArrayList which ultimately gets adapted for the UI via an Adapter.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mSessionPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.session_shared_preferences_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    networks = getListView();

    networkItems = new ArrayList<Network>();
    listAdapter = new NetworksListAdapter(getActivity(), networkItems);
    networks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put("user_id", mSessionPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.user_id_key), null))
          .put("auth_token", mSessionPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.user_auth_token_key), null));

    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            JSONArray jsonNetworks = response.optJSONArray("networks");
            int len = jsonNetworks.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonNetwork = jsonNetworks.optJSONObject(i);
                Network network = new Network(jsonNetwork.optString("external_id"),
                            jsonNetwork.optString("name");

                networkItems.add(network);
            }

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyErrorHandler volleyError = new VolleyErrorHandler(error);

            Log.v("Sigh", volleyError.getMessage(), "nope"));
        }
    };

    APIRequestManager.getInstance().doRequest().getNetworks(params, listener, errorListener);
}
```

The last line takes care of having Volley send the request.

Is there anything that looks suspicious? Note, this isn't on an emulator, it is on my actual device. I was under the impression that it handles the Async stuff. Should I be doing things with my listeners in the background explicitly? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Volley does in fact handle its workload in the background. The listeners however, or run by default on the UI thread - which is your responsibilty. If you're skipping frames, it's some sort of long operation that is performed on the UI thread. Try putting informative log prints to find out exactly where that operation is and move it to a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the length of jsonNetworks is large, you should run this method on background.
try this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONArray jsonNetworks = response.optJSONArray("networks");
            int len = jsonNetworks.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonNetwork = jsonNetworks.optJSONObject(i);
                Network network = new Network(jsonNetwork.optString("external_id"),
                        jsonNetwork.optString("name");

                networkItems.add(network);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: This concept seems right and should work, but I don't think your code is correct.

Comment: Okay, so I alleviated one issue which was that `runOnUiThread`needs to be `getActivity().runOnUiThread` since this is a fragment. The only other issue is that I reference `response` and it isn't a final variable.

Comment: Fixed it. Right above the line `new Thread(new Runnable() {`, I just wrote `final JSONObject jsonResponse = response;` and substituted response with jsonResponse.

Comment: Well... if there's a lot of data that need to be processed, showing progress dialog/bar would be a good idea? Is it possible to do that in onResponse from volley without risking leaked windows?